# How to show json format data in table format in flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I have data in json format and I want to represent data in below picture format:

[image: 1]

Comment: can you please tell me that are you using any table widget?

Comment: no dear am new on flutter if you know any thing related to this picture please help me

Comment: follow below given solution hope it may help you. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

You might want to give [json_table](https://pub.dev/packages/json_table) a try, It gets the job done.

If you want Images to be shown on the top as well, you can use a simple `Row` and show data using `json_table` without top row.